# Cannot connect to SQL Server via VB.net but I can login to the server from SSMS with the same cridentials

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2014

I'm working on an application in VB which has to connect to a SQL Server 2014 Express database with the following info:

```
DBName: testDB
DBHost: USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS
DBUser: testuser
DBPass: testpass
```

and the following code to make the connection:

```
Public Shared Sub connect(DBName As String, DBHost As String, DBUser As String, DBPass As String)

    Dim builder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder()
    builder.DataSource = DBHost
    builder.UserID = DBUser
    builder.Password = DBPass
    builder.InitialCatalog = DBName

    connection = New SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString)
    connection.Open()

End Sub
```

I'm able to login normally with this information (using SSMS) but not with the code here. Now I know that this code works as I've used it on a different machine where it worked fine. In both cases the server is hosted locally. I've enabled all protocols in the Network Configuration but I'm still not able to login via this code. Also I set the login to also work with SQL login.

I'm printing the exception it gives me and it sais

> Cannot open database "TestDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'testuser'.

Why does it allow me to login via SSMS and not via my program?

Comment: What do the logs in SQL Server say? Can you see the connection?

Comment: @Larnu I got the log file and found a whole bunch of these: `11/22/2018 19:17:21,Logon,Unknown,Login failed for user 'testuser'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'TestDB'. [CLIENT: <local machine>]` I guess this is from my testing to login from the program itself..

Comment: Does that database (TestDB) exist?  Does that user (TestUser) have access to the database?  You say you can logon with SSMS -- can you execute the command `USE TestDB;` in SSMS without error using those credentials?

Comment: Try to vary this row:  `Dim builder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Integrated Security=SSPI;")` OR `Dim builder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Integrated Security=true;")`

Comment: @DaveCullum the database and user exist and I'm able to execute that command.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have two instances installed?  When you run SSMS does the server have the \SQLEXPRESS name too?  If you check services.msc do you see multiple SQL Server instances?  Odd...

Comment: @StepUp It works! But I'm wondering how I was able to connect to the DB with the same code on a different machine with the same setup?

Comment: @DaveCullum Yes. There is only one service and the server has the sane name too!

Comment: Using `Integrated Security` in your connection string means you are no longer using the supplied user name and password. This is just a lucky guess and doesn't address the issue. The issue is that your user is not set up the same. You need to ensure that the user has been granted access to the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to vary this row:

```
Dim builder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New 
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Integrated Security=SSPI;")
```

OR

```
Dim builder As SqlConnectionStringBuilder = New 
    SqlConnectionStringBuilder("Integrated Security=true;")
```

What this means:

`Integrated Security = False` : User ID and Password are specified in the connection.

`Integrated Security = true` : the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication. However, be carefully it does not work in all SQL providers. It will throw an exception with `OleDb` provider.

`Integrated Security = SSPI` : this is equivalent to true, but it works with `SQL Client` and `OleDb` providers.

[Please, see connection strings at MSDN.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax)

Your error `Cannot open database "TestDB" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'testuser'.` means:

- you've written incorrect login or user of database `TestDB`
- user `testuser` does not exist in your **database**

Run to see whether `testuser` exists in your database:

```
USE YourDatabase
SELECT * FROM sysusers
```

In addition, be sure that you've set a correct password of database user.

**Update by Nick.McDermaid:**

**I was able to detirmine that I need to grand acess to the database for that user!**

Comment: Thanks for the info. i was able to detirmine that I need to grand acess to the database for that user!

Comment: ..as I said in my comment. The answer is not to change the authentication type, it is to grant the user access.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yeah, you are right! I've updated my answer. If you want to make an answer, feel free to do it as you were the first.